Collation error importing a database using DDEV
I am running a site locally using DDEV, the remote site is on shared hosting (siteground). I created an SQL dump using SSH on the remote site, then imported the database using ddev import-db.  The import failed with the following message:  ERROR 1273 (HY000) at line 25: Unknown collation: 'utf8mb4_0900_ai_ci'
There are several answers related to the error message "ERROR 1273 (HY000) at line 25: Unknown collation: 'utf8mb4_0900_ai_ci'"  Most of them involved using a text editor to replace "utf8mb4_0900_ai_ci" with "utf8mb4_general_ci".  I did not want to do this, because I would have to edit the database every time I synced the site as part of my workflow.
I used phpadmin to look at the database on the remote site at Siteground, and discovered that they were using mysql 8.0.  I looked at the file: .ddev/config.yaml and saw (line 11) database: /type: mariadb/ version: "10.4"  I CHANGED that yaml file to read database: /type: mysql/ version: "8.0"
After that, I entered ddev restart
At that point, I was able to import the database using ddev import-db successfully.  I entered ddev drush cr to clear the cache on the new database and the site worked correctly after that.
I hope that this helps other developers.

It looks to me like your database upstream on the host was mysql:8.0, so you did exactly the right thing, changing DDEV to mysql:8.0.

If you just used mariadb:10.11 (or newer) you could have upgrade to utf8mb4_1400_ai_ci, a newer standard.
That would also have also solved without needing to downgrade the collation to something that isn't even a standard (utf8mb4_general_ci).
Also: MariaDB 10.4 just had its last release and is officially EOL next month.
